# grep file for pattern without dot/extension and delete both with next line if empty

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a file containg data like this:
https://pastebin.com/TXrmVpwF
What I am trying to achieve is to find and remove all lines having pattern but not having extension or dot in name and if true remove empty lines after:

Patterns:

```
# /x/123

# /x/test

# /x/test_backup

# /x/123/10
```

Comment: If you want all the lines that begin with /x/, just run  `grep '/x/' file`

Comment: Which _pattern_? Can you describe it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a sample of the input, as well as the expected output and tell the actual operation you want done. Right now, it's not at all clear what you mean with "having pattern but not having extension or dot in name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the file is a Unix text file (and not a DOS text file, in which case you should run `dos2unix` over it first):

```
sed '/^#/{ /\./!{ N; /\n$/d; }; }' <file
```

Annotated `sed` script:

```
/^#/{           # The current line starts with a "#"
    /\./!{      # The current line does not contain a dot
        N;      # Append next line with a \n in-between
        /\n$/d; # The line just appended was empty, delete, start next cycle
    }
}
                # (implicit print)
```

If dots are allowed in the directory names but not in the last pathname component (i.e. `# /x.x/text` should be removed if followed by an empty line), then change `/\./` to `/\.[^/]*$/`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel sure about the question, but I think that this would be the answer:

```
grep -v '\.' TXrmVpwF | grep -e '/'
```

grep -v `'\.'`:   filter-out the lines with dots.

grep -e `'/'`:   take the rest of the paths.

This are the results:

```
# /x/123
# /x/test
# /x/test_backup
# /x/123/10
# /x/123/100
# /x/123/103
# /x/123/1333
```